# How do I see the user database of people who have signed up in my Rails app deployed in Heroku?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am currently using postgresql (Heroku addon) and I need to know the login credentials of people signing up in my web app at Heroku. Can anybody suggest me where to find the user database?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps to check tables data on heroku:

1. Login with heroku and goto your app.
2. Click dropdown from top right corner and select `console`
3. Now you have rails console open and able to check data in tables like `User.all`